# Simpler alternative to hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, pdf

I've been trying to get a hyperlinked table of contents working with a preexisting large book project. I've tried hyperref, and have had problems getting it to work right. In case it's of interest, I'll append a brief description of the problems, but the long and the short of it is that I'm getting the impression of hyperref as a big, complex, fragile package that includes a lot of unrelated functionality such as PDF titling, and I don't want to use it. Is there any alternative that will allow me to do something more low-level and just generate the hyperlinks I want? All I want is something like this:

```
\target{about-socrates}Socrates was sentenced to execution by drinking hemlock.
...
We recall that \href{about-socrates}{Socrates} drank hemlock.
```

That's all I need. I don't need it to do any styling of links for me (colors, boxes, etc.) -- I can handle that myself. I only need it to work with PDF output, not DVI, HTML, etc. I don't need it to automatically generate hyperlinks in the TOC; I think I can do that myself as well.

*Description of the problems with hyperref (probably irrelevant)*

I get a cryptic error message if I invoke hyperref after all other packages (`! Package hyperref Error: This should not happen! (hyperref) Missing version of 'hpdftex.def'.`), and although this error goes away if I invoke it before other packages, then some of the page numbers it links to are wrong. Unfortunately I have not had any luck getting a MWE to demonstrate either problem.

Comment: It's no answer to your question (well, I know of no other package), but what is precisely your problem? Please post a MWE in order to show the issue. I agree with you, that the various `\href` commands from `hyperref` might be confusing a little bit

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: The problem is described in the final paragraph. As explained there, I tried but failed to produce a MWE.

Comment: Ok, that error message is strange (can't remember to have seen it before...) If I understand your question correctly, you try to place hyperlinks somewhere in the text?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: *If I understand your question correctly, you try to place hyperlinks somewhere in the text?* Yes, that's right. I'm just looking for a very minimal, simple way of achieving that one task.

Comment: I have to admit that I've more-or-less given up on hyperlinks except when using `beamer` in part because every time I solved one issue, I seemed to create another. I don't think there is any other option, though. Everything which isn't `hyperref` seems to use `hyperref`. PDF metadata (title etc.) is actually easy but I don't think that requires `hyperref`. If you really want to go low level, you should look at the documentation for pdfTeX but I doubt that will prove simpler than `hyperref`.

Comment: To produce an MWE, you just comment stuff out until the error disappears. Then uncomment whatever you last commented and try commenting something else until commenting anything further will make the error go away. It is just a mechanical process so it is always possible to produce one. Just it is sometimes more tedious than other times.

Comment: @cfr: As stated in the question, I tried that and failed. As stated in the question, I simply have gotten the impression of hyperref as a piece of software that is big, complex, and fragile, and for that reason I don't want to use it.

Comment: @cfr: Writing `\pdfobj` stuff is hell ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Quite ;). I don't envy the author of `hyperref` at all. However, that doesn't mean I've succeeded in getting to grips with it :(.

Comment: @BenCrowell: `hyperref` is complex, given its functionality, that's true. It's big... yes, somehow... fragile? Well, I use only some of its features, but I have not expeared it to be fragile

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: My question was not, "Is hyperref good?" My question was whether there is an alternative.

Comment: @BenCrowell: I'll delete my answer... I am looking forward if somebody else post an answer concerning an alternative

Comment: The error message indicates that your `hyperref` installation is broken. All its files should come from the same version. The `.log` file tells, where the files (e.g. `hyperref.sty`, `hpdftex.def`) are found.

Comment: @BenCrowell If you can't provide a MWE, it is going to be really difficult for anybody to guess what is wrong. As I say, producing one is just tedious - it is a mechanical procedure you go through. Sometimes it takes a while. Sometimes you can make a lucky or informed guess and get there quicker. But the slow, tedious way is always an option when you are unlucky and uninformed. (As I often find I am.) If you really don't want to use `hyperref` then, short of using the low-level pdfTeX stuff, I think you have to give up hyperlinks.

Comment: @cfr: As stated in the question, I am not looking for help with fixing the problem with hyperref. I am looking for an alternative to hyperref.

Comment: In that case, I second @ChristianHupfer's comment.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: That's interesting, thanks, +1, but as stated in the question, I am not looking for a diagnosis of the problem with hyperref. I am asking for an alternative to hyperref.

Comment: I had a problem with hyperref as well. It should be a corruption error of the package's files. for me I went in the miktex console, clicked on **Packages** typed 'hyperref' and (re)install all that come out the search. After my problem was solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`navigator`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/navigator) package.

> Nav­i­ga­tor im­ple­ments PDF fea­tures for all for­mats (with some lim­i­ta­tions in ConTEXt) with PDFTEX, LuaTEX and X∃TEX (i.e. xd­vipdfmx). Fea­tures in­clude:
>
> - Cus­tomiz­able out­lines (i.e. book­marks);
> - An­chors;
> - Links and ac­tions (e.g. JavaScript or user-de­fined PDF ac­tions);
> - File em­bed­ding (not in ConTEXt);
> - Doc­u­ment in­for­ma­tion and PDF viewer's dis­play (not in ConTEXt); and
> - Com­mands to cre­ate and use raw PDF ob­jects
>
> Nav­i­ga­tor re­quires `texapi` and `yax`, both ver­sion at least 1.03.

Using `navigator`, the code snippet you included above would look like

```
\anchor{about-socrates}Socrates was sentenced to execution by drinking hemlock.
...
We recall that \jumplink{about-socrates}{Socrates} drank hemlock.
```

Comment: (+1) Never heard of this. Looks intriguing. (Though I do wish there were not quite so many different key-value systems. Not the fault of this package. Just the cumulative effect of lots of packages choosing different things.)